# i need to get post, featured image with specific category id wordpress by custom query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

i need to get post and featured image with specific category id in wordpress by custom query. This is my query:

```
SELECT p.ID, post_title AS title, post_excerpt AS excerpt,t.name AS name_cat ,bb.meta_value AS url_image FROM ap_posts p 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT p1.ID,wm2.meta_value FROM ap_posts p1 
    LEFT JOIN ap_postmeta wm1 ON ( wm1.post_id = p1.id AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' ) 
    LEFT JOIN ap_postmeta wm2 ON ( wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL ) ) AS bb ON p.ID = bb.ID 
    JOIN ap_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id) 
    JOIN ap_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
    JOIN ap_terms t ON (tt.term_id = t.term_id) WHERE p.post_type='post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND t.term_id =$cat_id ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

The result is ok, but it run slow because i use many "JOIN". How can i optimize this sql to increase performance. Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.,

```
$args = array(
'post_type'=>'posttype',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'person', //taxonomy name
            'field' => 'name',  //category field
            'terms' => 'bob'   //category name 
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_testimonials = $query->posts;
 $image= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_testimonials[0]->ID),'full');
var_dump($image);
```

Use about code **$image** variable gives URL of featured image. Loop the posts will get in query.

Answer (score 0):

On `ap_postmeta`, change the PK to `PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key)`.